# I cant save destiny 2 data at all to a usb for Ps4

Tags: ps4

Im not getting an option to save destiny 2 data on any account and Im trying to transfer data to another account on the same ps4 but cant and the account im trying to save the data on is most likely Hacked, can any one help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can only transfer data from to the same account on a different platform. Bungie may be able to help you get some of your data back.

Comment: They dont transfer data to another accounts

Comment: They do. You can link your PS4 account with your PC account, or with your XBOX account, or with your Stadia account. The point is, the game supports cross-save, but you can't switch the save with a different account on the same platform. Imagine Destiny not as a save, but as an account.